# Sqlite undefined reference to `sqlite3_open' error in Netbeans C++ on Ubuntu, Integrating SQLite into Netbeans C++ Ubuntu

Tags: c++, sqlite, netbeans, ubuntu

I am trying to use Sqlite in my Netbeans C++ and following the tutorial here
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/122300-sqlite-in-c/

When i build it,its giving me undefined  reference  to `sqlite3_open' and the other sqlite3 functions. I included the sqlite3.h too. What am i missing here?

When i added the linker to static library libsqlite3.a in project properties, my undefined reference errors are gone but now its giving me

/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o): In function `pthreadMutexTry':
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o): In function`pthreadMutexAlloc':
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o): In function `pthreadMutexAlloc':
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o): In function`pthreadMutexAlloc':
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o): In function `unixDlError':
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o): In function`findLockInfo':
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o): In function `findLockInfo':
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o): In function`unixDlSym':
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o): In function `unixDlClose':
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o): In function`unixDlOpen':
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cddb] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

And if i include the sqlite3ext.h, I get

main.cpp:20: error: ‘sqlite3_api’ was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 2):

### (please see EDIT below)

Not sure how C++ works in NetBeans, but your adding `libsqlite3.a` looks pretty good. Now if you have a Makefile you could edit it and define (or edit) the `LDFLAGS` variable, and pass it as an option to the linker...

SQLite in its default configuration needs to link with **libdl** and **libpthread**, that is why you might need to add `-ldl -lpthread` to your linking options.

For instance (if this is possible in NetBeans) add this to your Makefile :

```
LDFLAGS= -ldl -lpthread
```

In my projects I use it like so :

```
target: $(OBJ)
    gcc $(LDFLAGS)  $(OBJ) -o $@
```

### EDIT :

Actually it is also possible to add linker options in the GUI, without editing the Makefile by hand :

In submenu Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Command Line, just add `-ldl -lpthread` in "Additional options" and recompile your project.

Comment: Thanks! Hope it helps others.
Just before i tried your solution, i remembered that i installed both sqlite3 and sqlite2 and decided to remove both and install only sqlite3 again. I  mistakenly uninstalled a lot more packages than just sqlite3 which sort of crashed my whole Ubuntu. I got a clean .iso and started all over again.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating Sqlite into Netbeans on Linux
1)Synaptic Package Manager - Install libsqlite3-dev
2)Netbeans->Your_Project Properties->Linker->Libraries->Add Library-> libsqlite3.a
3)#include sqlite3.h
It works!