# How to use SQLite with c++ on Ubuntu? (undefined reference error)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sqlite

I want to use SQLite with c++ on Ubuntu. I chose to try the example from https://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html. But when running `c++ test.cpp -o test` I get the error:

```
/tmp/ccTwwjKw.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
test.cpp:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `sqlite3_errmsg'
test.cpp:(.text+0x12e): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
test.cpp:(.text+0x15d): undefined reference to `sqlite3_exec'
test.cpp:(.text+0x18f): undefined reference to `sqlite3_free'
test.cpp:(.text+0x19b): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
collect2: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
```

I think the Problem is the same as here: [Sqlite undefined reference to `sqlite3_open' error in Netbeans C++ on Ubuntu, Integrating SQLite into Netbeans C++ Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463438). But I have no make file and I don't use netbeans.

Comment: I found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090639.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a linker error and you are not linking to any libraries. Link to the correct libraries using -llibname where libname is the name of your library with lib removed from the start. For example if the libname is libsqlite3.so try adding `-lsqlite3` at the end of your compilation step. Of course you need to also provide the path to that library if it is in a non standard place using the `-L/path/to/lib` option and obviously you will need to have installed the relevant library first.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the lib for sqlite is -libsqlite or -libsqlite3.

Comment: Yes thanks. That's what was in the thread I linked above. `-lsqlite3` at the end of the command did the magic.